# Beautifulsoup findAll returns an empty list or none

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a webpage using beautifulsoup, but findAll() returns an empty list. This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://mokka-home.nl/product/bank-campania/"

# Make a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Extract the product title
title = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'product_title entry-title'}).text.strip()

# Extract the product price
price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'woocommerce-Price-amount amount'}).text.strip()

# Extract all product images
images = [img['src'] for img in soup.find_all('img', {'class': 'wp-post-image'})]

# Print the scraped data
print("Title: ", title)
print("Price: ", price)
print("Images: ", images)
```

Im getting this error:

```
title = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'product_title'}).text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

And if I get the `.text.strip()` off I'm getting none and an empty image list:

```
Title:  None
Price:  None
Images:  []
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked what `response.content` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `headers` and you should be fine.

For example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://mokka-home.nl/product/bank-campania/"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/112.0.1722.54",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

# Extract the product title
title = soup.select_one(".product--summary .product_title").getText(strip=True)

# Extract the product price
price = soup.select_one(".product--summary .single-price-wrapper .price .amount").getText(strip=True)

# Extract all product images
images = [img['src'] for img in soup.find_all('img', {'class': 'wp-post-image'})]

# Print the scraped data
print("Title: ", title)
print("Price: ", price)
print("Images: ", images)
```

Output:

```
Title:  CHESTERFIELD BANKSTEL CAMPANIA
Price:  €1.339,00
Images:  ['https://b2001162.smushcdn.com/2001162/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/bolton-6.jpg?lossy=1&strip=1&webp=1']
```